# jQuery: Find the previous visible `li` with visible `A` tag

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a list like this:

```
<ul>
  <li><a >11</a></li>
  <li><a>22</a></li>
  <li><a style="display:none;">33</a></li>
  <li style="display:none;"><a>55</a></li>
  <li class="active"><a>55</a></li>
  <li><a>66</a></li>
</ul>
```

From the active `li` tag I want to get the previous visible `li` tag with visible `a` tag.

If I try like this:

`$('li.active').prevAll(":visible:first")` // 33

it will give the previous first visible `li` but its `a` is not visible.

When I'm trying to find the previous it has to return 22.

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use method chaining to achieve it

Below code will get the first element `11`

```
$('li.active').prevAll().find(":visible").first()
```

Below code will get the last element `22`

```
$('li.active').prevAll().find(":visible").last()
```

If there is only one child tag which is display none, then there is no need to check the child tag visibility

Demo

```js
$('li.active').prevAll().find(":visible").last().css("color","red")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a >11</a></li>
  <li><a>22</a></li>
  <li><a style="display:none;">33</a></li>
  <li style="display:none;"><a>55</a></li>
  <li class="active"><a>55</a></li>
  <li><a>66</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

A relatively flexible jQuery solution would be:

- Get all the previous visible `li`
- Inside those, find the visible `a`
- Get the parent `li` from those visible `a`
- Get the last match from the remaining elements

Code example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('li.active')
    .prevAll('li:visible') // Get all the previous visible `li`
    .find('a:visible') // Inside those, get the visible `a`
    .parent() // Get the parent `li` from the visible `a` 
    .last() // Get the last match
    
    // Add a style to show the example working
    .css({
      'color': 'red'
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a>11</a></li>
  <li><a>22</a></li>
  <li><a style="display:none;">33</a></li>
  <li style="display:none;"><a>55</a></li>
  <li class="active"><a>55</a></li>
  <li><a>66</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this in vanilla ES5 JavaScript.

1. Start with the list and find the active list item
2. Get the previous sibling of the active item
3. Now loop through the siblings making sure that the `li` and `a` elements are "visible"

```js
const isVisible = el => el.style && el.style.display !== 'none';
const findPrevActiveSibling = ul => {
  if (typeof ul === 'string') ul = document.querySelector(ul);
  let active = ul.querySelector('li.active'),
    prev = active.previousSibling;
  while (prev) {
    if (isVisible(prev) && isVisible(prev.querySelector('a'))) {
      return prev;
    }
    prev = prev.previousSibling;
  }
  return null;
};

console.log(findPrevActiveSibling('ul').textContent); // 22
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a >11</a></li>
  <li><a>22</a></li>
  <li><a style="display:none;">33</a></li>
  <li style="display:none;"><a>55</a></li>
  <li class="active"><a>55</a></li>
  <li><a>66</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here is the jQuery version.

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.prevActiveItem = function(activeClass) {
    const $active = this.find('.' + (activeClass || 'active'));
    let $prev = $active.prev();
    while ($prev.length) {
      if ($prev.is(':visible') && $prev.find('a').is(':visible')) {
        return $prev;
      }
      $prev = $prev.prev();
    }
    return null;
  };
})(jQuery);

console.log($('ul').prevActiveItem().text()); // 22
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a >11</a></li>
  <li><a>22</a></li>
  <li><a style="display:none;">33</a></li>
  <li style="display:none;"><a>55</a></li>
  <li class="active"><a>55</a></li>
  <li><a>66</a></li>
</ul>
```